# Trying to understand PDO and arrays

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

I'm trying to learn PDO and PHP.
Let's say I have a array like the one below:

```
$_var1 = [

   'key' => [
       'title' => 'Title',
       'icon' => 'icon1',
       'items' => [
                     'set1' => [
                                 'title' => 'Subtitle1',
                                 'url' => 'url'
                                ],
                     'set2' => [
                                 'title' => 'Subtitle 2',
                                 'url' => 'url'
                                ]
                  ]
             ],

];
```

I'm trying to wrap my head around how this would look in SQL db and how one would read this back from SQL via PDO.

I've tried creating 2 tables ; parent and child ;

```
PARENT

    id      (ai)
    nav_key varchar(256)    utf8mb4_general_ci   
    title   varchar(256)    utf8mb4_general_ci  
    icon    varchar(256)    utf8mb4_general_ci  
    item    varchar(256)    utf8mb4_general_ci      

CHILD


    id          (ai)
    parent_id   varchar(256)    utf8mb4_general_ci      
    set         varchar(256)    utf8mb4_general_ci
    title2      varchar(256)    utf8mb4_general_ci
    url         varchar(256)    utf8mb4_general_ci
```

```
SELECT  parent.nav_key, parent.title, parent.icon, parent.item, 
        child.set, child.title2, child.url 
FROM parent 
    JOIN child on parent.id = child.parent_id
```

```
    Array ( 
        [0] => Array 
                ( [nav_key] => 
                            [title] => test1 
                            [icon] => icon1 
                            [item] => 
                            [set] => 
                            [title2] => sub1 
                            [url] => suburl 
                ) 
       )
```

It looks close, but I'm stuck........

I'm trying to get the output of the query to match the PHP array.

------------------------EDIT BELOW -----------------------

So I'm still trying to understand this. User "your common sense" had pointed me in the right direction (I assume)
So I went to his site, and looked at the example (Example below)

```
$sql = "SELECT c.id as c_id, c.name as c_name, c.url, 
           p.id as p_id, p.name as p_name, p.price
    FROM category c
    JOIN product p ON p.category_id=c.id
    ORDER BY c.name, p.name
    LIMIT ?,?";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$start, $limit]);

$data = [];
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
if (!isset($data[$row['c_id']])) {
    $row['c_id'] = [
        'name' => $row['c_name'],
        'url' => $row['url'],
        'products' => [
            [
                'id' => $row['p_id'],
                'name' => $row['p_name'],
                'price' => $row['price'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
  } else {
    $row['c_id']['products'][] = [
        'id' => $row['p_id'],
        'name' => $row['p_name'],
        'price' => $row['price'],
    ];
    }
}
```

This should create an array like the one I'm talking about.
However if I copy this code, and make the db, it will not work.

I made the db and I see the query running on the mysql command line.
if I `print_r($stmt)` I see the correct query, if I manually enter the query into SQL it returns values, the $data array is empty though... I don't get it.

What am I missing here?

Comment: It does help if the tables you describe match the columns you have in your query

Comment: Do you have 2 rows in the `child` table, linked to this parent?

Comment: i might be missing somethiing huge, but what do you mean with linked to this parent? I join the 2 tables based on the matching id (parent_id = child.parent_id)

Comment: Sorry for parent read `main`

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? or perhaps point me into the right docs that cover this

Comment: Look, your descriptions dont make sense. `JOIN child WHERE main.id = child.parent_id'` there is no `parent_id` column in the `child` table. I know what you mean but little things like this mean we have to make assumptions that you actually did things correctly as you claim to be getting a result from the query. Assumptions are dangerous, so people just ignore the question and go to one that does make sense

Comment: DITTO: You dont have a `key` column in either table but you claim to be getting a property in the resulting object that has the name `key`? Not possible, with the DB and PHP code you show us !

Comment: Ill try and reformat everything man, i get what your saying im sorry, ill fix it right now

Comment: i edited the original questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you have to understand is that **you cannot get a nested structure from a database**. The returned data is always a rectangular table.

Although PDO can emulate a nested structure with [PDO::FETCH_GROUP](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#group) fetch modifier, it will take only a single field from the parent table which is not suitable for you.

The simplest solution for you would be to run two queries. the first one to get data from the main table and the second one is to fetch related items from the child table. then you could assign the second result to the new field of the main table result.

Of course it could be done with a JOIN as well, but it will need some post-processing as it will return a lot of duplicated data.

To make this answer complete, there is a way to get a structure like this right off the query. You will need an advanced ORM for this, like Doctrine. There, you define the tables and relations between them first, and it will get you such a structure based on these definitions. There is a learning curve though.

Comment: Hi, thnx for the information, could you give me an example of how one would approach filling the array like i need using 2 queries?

Comment: Given this code could be useful for many people, I wrote an article on my site with the example, [Getting a nested array when multiple rows are linked to a single entry](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/nested_array)

Comment: i checked out your link, and duplicated your code there, however the resulting array is empty? i commented , however comments do not show up?